# I need a Promise within a Promise and its .then to run first

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, es6-promise

So, I'm reading this XML file:

```xml
<GlDocumentInfo xmlns:opt="Opt.GL.Domain" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="Opt.GL.BusinessLogic">
  <world version="1.0.5">
    <GlDocument key="GlDocument:1">
        <GlDocumentNetwork>
            <Network key="Network:1">
                <Paths>
                    <Path key="Path:1" IsEmpty="False">
                        <PathNodes>
                            <PathNode key="PathNode:1" Node="Node:1" />
                            <PathNode key="PathNode:2" Node="Node:15" Distance="500" />
                            <PathNode key="PathNode:3" Node="Node:13" Distance="320" />
                            <PathNode key="PathNode:4" Node="Node:4" Distance="300" />
                            <PathNode key="PathNode:5" Node="Node:14" Distance="450" />
                        </PathNodes>
                    </Path>
                    <Path key="Path:2" IsEmpty="False">
                        <PathNodes>
                            <PathNode key="PathNode:5" Node="Node:14" />
                            <PathNode key="PathNode:6" Node="Node:4" Distance="450" />
                            <PathNode key="PathNode:7" Node="Node:13" Distance="300" />
                            <PathNode key="PathNode:8" Node="Node:15" Distance="320" />
                            <PathNode key="PathNode:9" Node="Node:1" Distance="500" />
                        </PathNodes>
                    </Path>
                </Paths>
               </Network>
       </GLDocument>
    </world>
</DocumentInfo>
```

A Path is a schema with this format:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var Path = new Schema({
    key: {type: String, unique: true},
    isEmpty: Boolean,
    pathNodes: [String]
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Path', Path);
```

And a PathNode is a schema with this format:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var PathNode = new Schema({
    key: String,
    node: String,
    distance: Number
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('PathNode', PathNode);
```

So I need to read each **PathNode** of each **Path**, create them and save them to the DB, aswell as saving those PathNodes of the current Path in an array, to then create the Path and being able to assign the array to that Path's *pathNodes* attribute, which is an array of Strings of those PathNodes as you can see.
The code I have is:

```js
var PathNode = require('../models/pathNode');
var Path = require('../models/path');
var repository = require('../../repository');

var jsonConverted = JSON.parse(convert.xml2json(req.file.buffer.toString(), { compact: true, spaces: 4, alwaysChildren: true }));
var pathNodesArray = [];

await Promise.all(jsonConverted.GlDocumentInfo.world.GlDocument.GlDocumentNetwork.Network.Paths.Path.map(async path => {

        pathNodesArray = [];
        await Promise.all(path.PathNodes.PathNode.map(async pathNode => {

            var newPathNode = new PathNode();
            newPathNode.key = pathNode._attributes.key;
            newPathNode.node = pathNode._attributes.Node; 
            newPathNode.duration = pathNode._attributes.Duration;
            newPathNode.distance = pathNode._attributes.Distance;

            pathNodesArray.push(newPathNode.key);

            repository.savePathNode(newPathNode);

        })).then(async () => {

            var newPath = new Path();
            newPath.key = path._attributes.key;
            newPath.isEmpty = path._attributes.IsEmpty.toString().toLowerCase();
            Object.assign(newPath.pathNodes, pathNodesArray);

            repository.savePath(newPath);
        });
    })).then(async () => {
(...) //doesn't matter for this question
}
```

The reading works fine, all PathNodes are being created and saved in the DB just fine, the problem is that **Path:1** and **Path:2** both are being saved with the same list of PathNodes, **Path:1** has the list of PathNodes from **Path:2**. So this *Promise* and *.then* inside the outter Promise is not working properly, because it's reading all PathNodes, and only then it reads the Paths, and assigns the last assembled array of PathNodes to the last Path.

Can you please help me solve this, so each **Path** has its according **PathNodes** ? I've tried removing the *async* from multiple places, *await* the save...
Thank you.

Comment: Don't use `.then(async () => {`. You're already `await`ing the promise, just put the code after the `await` statement instead of in a `then` callback.

Comment: Your using a very confusing combination of `async`/`await` and `then()`. This would be much easier to read if you just stuck to one or the other

Comment: @Bergi I did just that, yet, it saves the same PathNodes in both Paths. Despair is real at this point :c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the issue @Yevhenii mentioned, your `var pathNodesArray = [];` is in the wrong scope. You want each path to have its own path nodes arrays, and while doing `pathNodesArray = [];` in the loop might work if it was sequential, it fails when processing your paths in parallel. Prefer `const` over `var`:

```
const PathNode = require('../models/pathNode');
const Path = require('../models/path');
const repository = require('../../repository');

const jsonConverted = JSON.parse(convert.xml2json(req.file.buffer.toString(), { compact: true, spaces: 4, alwaysChildren: true }));
const paths = jsonConverted.GlDocumentInfo.world.GlDocument.GlDocumentNetwork.Network.Paths.Path;
await Promise.all(paths.map(async path => {
    const pathNodesArray = [];
//  ^^^^^ declare inside each iteration
    await Promise.all(path.PathNodes.PathNode.map(async pathNode => {
        const newPathNode = new PathNode({
            key: pathNode._attributes.key,
            node: pathNode._attributes.Node,
            duration: pathNode._attributes.Duration,
            distance: pathNode._attributes.Distance,
        });
        pathNodesArray.push(newPathNode.key);

        await repository.savePathNode(newPathNode);
//      ^^^^^
    }));

    const newPath = new Path({
        key: path._attributes.key,
        isEmpty: path._attributes.IsEmpty.toString().toLowerCase(),
        pathNodes: pathNodesArray,
    });

    await repository.savePath(newPath);
//  ^^^^^
}));
// … doesn't matter for this question
```

Comment: Thank you Bergi, this helped out! Have a wonderful day

Answer (score 1):

try adding `return` before `repository.savePathNode(newPathNode)`.
Now, it seams, that your nested promise isn't awaited

```js
...
await Promise.all(path.PathNodes.PathNode.map(async pathNode => {

            var newPathNode = new PathNode();
            newPathNode.key = pathNode._attributes.key;
            newPathNode.node = pathNode._attributes.Node; 
            newPathNode.duration = pathNode._attributes.Duration;
            newPathNode.distance = pathNode._attributes.Distance;

            pathNodesArray.push(newPathNode.key);

            return repository.savePathNode(newPathNode);

        }))
...
```

Comment: Thank you replying, yet, what should I return? because an empty return before the **repository.savePathNode(newPathNode);** will grey it out and it never reaches this statement